# AOV texture exports

Tags: cycles-render-engine, render-passes

I'm currently trying to export multiple versions of a tshirt on a single animation. I have been trying to set up an aov pass that exports the tshirt material (and therefore be able export multiple versions of tshirts using multiple aovs) however the aov is not showing anything in AE (I can see all of my other passes and the aov is included). Does anyone know a good workflow or tutorial that is doing this exact thing?

I know this can be done in C4D Redshift, so I'm assuming it can be done in blender cycles, right?!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a setup like this in C4D RS and needed to recreate it in Blender today.

Did this in Blender 3.3.0 on MacOS Monterey (12.6.1):

1. In Properties Panel -> View Layer Properties -> Passes -> Shader AOV add a Shader AOV - set its name (defaults to AOV) to something descriptive (in your case maybe shirt-color). Either set it to Color or Value, depending how you would like your output (I guess Value would be more perfomant in compositing later on?)
2. In the Material Shader Graph of the desired Shader you can now add a AOV Output Node (not available until you set up a AOV as described in step 1). This node can just float there and does not need to be attatched to anything BUT it has to has the correct naming.
3. Set the AOV Output Nodes name to the same name as you did in the View Layer Properties and set the Color (or Value, depending on your setting of the Shader AOV in the Layer Properties) - now they are connected.
4. Your AOV will now be available to the renderer.
   You can make sure it works by rendering a frame and then checking the layers in blenders render viewer (on the top right) - there should be your AOV available by the name you set earlier. If it is not by default, try to select the right View Layer from the drop down to the right of the Slot Dropdown.

Links from the docs:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/passes.html#shader-aov

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/output/aov.html

Side note to everyone who's new to AOVs (or if I'll come back here one day because I forgot how all this is done!): Make sure to render out OpenEXR MultiLayer Files.
To interpret it in AfterEffects: Load the Footage in and use the EXtractoR Effect (shipped with AfterEffects).

Hope it helps!